# ngIf first item from array returning "cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') "

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am having trouble creating an ngIf statement in Angular. I am trying to show a div only when it would match a certain condition... but I keep getting this errorr in the browser console:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

What am I doing wrong?

My HTML is:

```
<div *ngIf="preSelectedPaymentOption[0].value === 3 && totalCartPrice > 380" class="payment-warning">
   <ion-label>
    <h3>Atention!</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit!!!.</p>
  </ion-label>
</div>
```

This is how the data from the API looks like:
[image: Api data console.log]

And here is the TS code how I'm getting the data:

```
  getPaymentOptions() {
    this.cartService.getPaymenyOptions().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.paymentData = data;
        this.preSelectedPaymentOption = this.paymentData.payments.filter(option => option.default === 1);
        console.log('Preselected payment method: ', this.preSelectedPaymentOption.map(option => option));
      }, error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `preSelectedPaymentOption` might be undefined at the start so changing your condition to following should fix the issue

```
*ngIf="!!preSelectedPaymentOption?.length && preSelectedPaymentOption[0].value === 3 && totalCartPrice > 380"
```

Comment: Hey, this works :) thank you!! Would you please explain why it worsk with this part of  added code ("!!preSelectedPaymentOption?.length")?

Comment: this will check if preSelectedPaymentOption have some items if it is undefined or don't have any item it will return false so will not check for other conditions until this condition is satisfied. About `?` you can find details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: thank you :) what would I have to change in my code so that I would first get the payment options and would be getting undefined?

Comment: you might have declared your `preSelectedPaymentOption` like `preSelectedPaymentOption:yourType[]` you can change it to `preSelectedPaymentOption:yourType[]=[] ` but then also get the issue because there is no item in the array and preSelectedPaymentOption[0] will be undefined.Another way is to defined one more boolean property and use that in ngif and then set it when you get your  preSelectedPaymentOption from api

Comment: This is how I'm definign my preSelectedPaymentOption: ' preSelectedPaymentOption: PaymenyOptions['payments'];'

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be the fact that the data is being fetched over the network (using a webservice, I assume) and there is no guard for the duration when the view has loaded but the value has not yet been retrieved yet.

Based on the answer by @jitender, you can check if `preSelectedPaymentOption` is not null before accessing it's value.

I would, however, recommend a cleaner full-RxJS approach as below:

```js
preSelectedPaymentOption$ = this.cartService.getPaymenyOptions()
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    tap((data) => {
      this.paymentData = data;
    }),
    map((data) => {
      return data.payments.filter((option => option.default === 1))
    }),
    tap((preSelectedPaymentOption) => {
      console.log('preselected payment method: ', preSelectedPaymentOption.map(option => option));
    }),
  );
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(preSelectedPaymentOption | async) as preSelectedPaymentOption">
  <div *ngIf="preSelectedPaymentOption[0].value === 3 && totalCartPrice > 380" class="payment-warning">
    <ion-label>
      <h3>Atention!</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit!!!.</p>
    </ion-label>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

It is not clear from your code if you have any other use for `preSelectedPaymentOption` other than simply checking if `preSelectedPaymentOption[0].value === 3`.

If you don't need access to `preSelectedPaymentOption` for anything else except to check if the value === 3, then you can include that in the observable too:

```js
isPreSelectedPaymentOption$ = this.cartService.getPaymenyOptions()
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    tap((data) => {
      this.paymentData = data;
    }),
    map((data) => {
      const allOptionDefaultsToOne = data.payments.filter((option => option.default === 1));
      return (allOptionDefaultsToOne?.[0]?.value === 3);
    }),
  );
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(isPreSelectedPaymentOption$ | async) && totalCartPrice > 380" class="payment-warning">
  <ion-label>
    <h3>Atention!</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit!!!.</p>
  </ion-label>
</div>
```

**Note**: I have not run this code, so it might contain errors. Please use your discretion.

Comment: Hey, thank you for this :) I do have another use for preSelectedPaymentOption... you mentioned a guard for the duration when the view has loaded but the value has not yet been retrieved... how could I implement such a guard?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. The guard here implies a simple check if the object is not null.
In your case it would be simply: `preSelectedPaymentOption && preSelectedPaymentOption[0] && preSelectedPaymentOption[0].value === 3 && totalCartPrice > 380`. It would have been simpler using optional chaining for the array with `preSelectedPaymentOption?.[0]?.value === 3`, but unfortunately, Angular does not support it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

The error could occur because of the Angular life cycle hooks.
Do you get the Data before the Template is build?

Here is the angular life cycle hook documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks